# Padding doesn't work when size is 63 and 27

Tags: python, numpy, svm, pad

During the iteration, almost all out of 100 arrays get padded apart from two whose sizes are 63 and 27. As a result SVM doesn't work because of size differences of feature arrays.

I tried iterating through once again at the bottom but didn't work. Tried to change the dimensions using a conditional statement, didn't work.

```py
for idx1, f in enumerate(feature):
        if idx1 >= 50: break
        current_feature.append(f[2])
        current_feature.append(f[3])
        current_feature.append(f[4])

    #fixations.append(feature.feature_list)
    current_feature = np.array(current_feature)
    pad_amount = 150 - current_feature.size
    prev = current_feature.size
    np.pad(current_feature, (0, pad_amount), 'constant')
    if current_feature.size != 150:
        np.pad(current_feature, (0, pad_amount), 'constant')
        print(prev)
        print(current_feature.size)
    feed.append(current_feature)
```

Out of the 100 feature arrays create only two with sizes 67 and 27 will not be padded.

EDIT: Typo while pasting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.pad don't change the array inplace, it returns new array. Try `current_feature = np.pad(current_feature, (0, pad_amount), 'constant')`

(You can remove the first appearance of `np.pad(current_feature, (0, pad_amount), 'constant')`, for the same reason).